# Best way to send data to an SNS topic from Dyanmodb for 2 cases - existing data and any new incoming data with low latency

Tags: aws-lambda, stream, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sns, amazon-kinesis

Trying to design a workflow that can send data from a dynamodb to an sns topic.
I need to make sure that latency is as low as possible.

Currently looking into if kinesis or dynamodb streams can help here since I already have kinesis data streams available for me to use. But I still want to make sure I choose a component that helps reduce latency.

1. Which is one is better for my use-case - Kinesis data streams/Dynamodb Streams? and
2. Do I absolutely need a lambda between the streams and the SNS
   queue?
3. What would be the best way to handle failures during this process? A DLQ that can retry/re-drive the failed records?

Little new to AWS and using its components.
Please do give me any suggestions that can help improve this design.

Comment: What do you mean by "send data from a dynamodb to an sns topic"? Are you wanting it to send a message to SNS whenever an item changes in a DynamoDB table? If so, why not use [DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html)?

Comment: Yes, when the trigger needs to be when an item changes and also for the backfill of existing data. 

I am confused between Kinesis data streams and DynamoDb streams. 
1. Which is one is better for my use-case and 
2. Do I absolutely need a lambda between the streams and the SNS queue?

Comment: Think of DynamoDB Streams as a special-purpose version of Kinesis, designed just for DynamoDB. Since you want to know when data changes in DynamoDB, you should use a DynamoDB Stream. You can then write an app that reads the records, or you can automatically trigger an AWS Lambda function when data is streamed ([DynamoDB Streams and AWS Lambda triggers - Amazon DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html)). There is no automatic method to send a DynamoDB Stream to an Amazon SNS topic, so you could use a Lambda function to send to the topic.